# Bad Color Referencing?

Tags: java, swing, colors, panel, paint

I am in the middle of designing a game very similar to Flow free. I have run into an issue in my code where I want to be able to click on a circle in the grid, be able to gauge its color, and then check if the color is white. If the color is white, I will then print error, which is a placeholder for now. However, even when I click on non-white tiles, I still see the error message being printed. What Am I doing wrong?

My Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; //JFrame Class
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class DriverV2 extends JPanel {


static ArrayList<Shape> circles;
static ArrayList<Color> colors;

public DriverV2() {
   circles = new ArrayList<Shape>();
   colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
   colors.add( Color.CYAN);//1
   colors.add( Color.BLUE);//2
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//3
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//4
   colors.add( Color.GREEN);//5
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//6
   colors.add( Color.CYAN);//7
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//8
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//9
   colors.add( Color.RED);//10
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//11
   colors.add( Color.YELLOW);//12
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//13
   colors.add( Color.GREEN);//14
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//15
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//16
   colors.add( Color.BLUE);//17
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//18
   colors.add( Color.RED);//19
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//20
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//21
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//22
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//23
   colors.add( Color.WHITE);//24
   colors.add( Color.YELLOW);//25
      int rows = 5;

   for (int y=0;y< rows;y++)
   {
      for (int x=0;x<rows;x++)
    {
        circles.add( new Ellipse2D.Double((x + 1) * 150, (y + 1) *150, 100, 100) );
    }
}
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    Color foreground = g2d.getColor();



   int h = 0;
    for (Shape shape : circles)
    {

        g2d.setColor( colors.get(h));
        g2d.draw( shape );
        g2d.fill(shape);
        h++;
    }
}
public static boolean checkLinearity(int index1, int index2){
   if((index1%5) == (index2 %5)) { //vertical line check
      return true;
   }
   if(Math.abs(index1-index2) < 5) { //horizantal line check
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }

}
static int counter = 0;
static int index1 = 0;
static int index2 = 0;
public static void main(String[] args)
      {

      JFrame f = new JFrame("Flow"); //new JFrame
      DriverV2 t = new DriverV2();
      f.setSize(900,900);//sets size of frame
      //  f.setLocation(100,50);//sets location of frame
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//sets default close operation
      //  f.setContentPane(new Panel()); //sets content pane
      f.setVisible(true);//makes panel visible
      f.add(t);
      f.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();

         for (Shape shape: circles) {

            if (shape.contains(x,y)) {
               counter++;
               if(counter % 2 == 1) {
                  index1 = circles.indexOf(shape)+1;
                  if(Color.WHITE.equals(colors.get(index1))) {
                     counter--;
                     System.out.println("error");
                  }
               }
               else{
                  index2 = circles.indexOf(shape) +1;
                  if(checkLinearity(index1, index2) == true) {
                     //I want to be able to draw a rectange here
                  }
               }


         }
}
         }
      });

}
}
```

Comment: Could we see your `class Shape`?

Comment: Note that indices are 0-based, so `colors.get(index1)` might be one off due to `index1 = circles.indexOf(shape)+1;`. Btw, since you're iterating over `circles` anyway there's no need for `circles.indexOf(shape)` - just count the loop iterations (again start at 0). Yet better, create a class `Circle` what contains the shape and the color. That way the indices of shapes and colors can't get out of sync due to programming errors.

Comment: @Thomas I know that's not the case because I tried clicking on everything in the grid and each time the error message was printed

Comment: @mackycheese21 Shape is a built in java interface, just google its documentation

Comment: @mackycheese21: he has no "class" Shape. He's referencing the core Java Shape interface. Please check the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems another example of why many people (including me) advocate to *always* add curly braces (even on 1-statement blocks - they might not stay that way):

Have a look at this snippet:

```
if (shape.contains(x,y)) 
   counter++;
     if(counter % 2 == 1) {
      ...
```

It doesn't do what you think, i.e. if you hit the shape `counter` get's increased but the rest of the checks is performed for *every* shape. That's because to the compiler the code looks like this:

```
if (shape.contains(x,y)) 
   counter++;
if(counter % 2 == 1) {
  ...
```

Thus, when you hit a circle `counter` will be 1 and hence `counter % 2 == 1` will be true for every circle being checked afterwards.

So, add curly braces around the indented code. Additionally you might want to break the loop once you've detected a hit since you're probably not interested in check all the other circles as well.

You might also want to introduce a class `Circle` which might look like this:

```
class Circle {
  Shape shape;
  Color color;

  ... //additional properties, e.g. position, and methods

  public boolean wasHit(int x, int y) {
    return shape.contains(x,y);
  }

  public boolean isValid() {
    return Color.WHITE.equals( color );
  }
}
```

Then you'd iterate over those like this:

```
for( Circle circle : circles ) {
  if( circle.wasHit(x, y) {
    if( circle.isValid() ) {
      //do what you'd need here, e.g. change the shape to a rectangle
    } else {
      //error
    }

    //break the loop since other circles can't be hit or we're not interested in those
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've added the curly braces and my code still does not appear to work. I've updated the question code to match now.

Comment: @shuryusd I don't see the curly braces in your updated post. You added some but those are at the wrong position - read my answer carefully.

Comment: @shuryusd now it looks better

Comment: I get it now, I just needed to remove the +1 I used in the indexes, It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to what Thomas mentioned (1+ to his answer) don't add your MouseListener to the JFrame. Add it instead to the JPanel that is doing the drawing, else your x and y positions will be off.

Myself, I would use a grid of JLabels, labels that hold icons. You can even give the labels row and column values as properties that can be retrieved. This would allow easy swapping of Icons if that is your goal, and would allow easy retrieval of *which* grid cell was pressed.

Some advangages:

- If the JLabels are also placed into a `List<JLabel>` then they can be shuffled easily if you need random placement of colors
- Error testing for white is easy. Simply get the icon from the selected JLabel and test for equality with the white icon: `if (label.getIcon == whiteIcon)`.
- Again, getting the row/column position of the selected disk is easy since it is an intrinsic property of the JLabel itself and can be retrieved by calling `getClientProperty` on the JLabel, for example: `label1.getClientProperty(ROW);`
- If you need to check for two mouse presses in a row, save the first mouse press result into a field of the class, here a JLabel called `label1`.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DriverV2b extends JPanel {
    private static final String ROW = "row";
    private static final String COLUMN = "column";
    private static final int DIM = 5;
    private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 150;
    private static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 100;
    private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[DIM][DIM];
    private Icon whiteIcon = createIcon(Color.WHITE);
    private Icon blueIcon = createIcon(Color.BLUE);
    private Icon greenIcon = createIcon(Color.GREEN);
    private Icon yellowIcon = createIcon(Color.YELLOW);
    private Icon redIcon = createIcon(Color.RED);
    private Icon[] coloredIcons = {blueIcon, greenIcon, yellowIcon, redIcon};
    private JLabel label1 = null;

    public DriverV2b() {
        // grid to hold the JLabels
        setLayout(new GridLayout(DIM, DIM));

        // mouse listener to add to all JLabels
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();

        // list of JLabels so we can shuffle them for random placement
        List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int row = 0; row < labelGrid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < labelGrid[row].length; col++) {
                // initially give all a white icon
                labelGrid[row][col] = new JLabel(whiteIcon);

                // add mouselistener
                labelGrid[row][col].addMouseListener(myMouse);

                // client property so we know what row and column the label is on
                labelGrid[row][col].putClientProperty(ROW, row);
                labelGrid[row][col].putClientProperty(COLUMN, col);

                // add JLabel to the array list
                labels.add(labelGrid[row][col]);

                // add it to the GUI
                add(labelGrid[row][col]);
            }
        }

        // shuffle the array list of JLabels, so we can add colored icons randomly
        Collections.shuffle(labels);

        // for each colored icon in the array, add *two** to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < coloredIcons.length; i++) {
            int index = 2 * i;
            labels.get(index).setIcon(coloredIcons[i]);
            labels.get(index + 1).setIcon(coloredIcons[i]);
        }
    }

    private Icon createIcon(Color color) {
        int w = ICON_WIDTH;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, w, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();

        // rendering hints used to smooth the image edges
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(color);
        int width = CIRCLE_WIDTH;
        int x = (ICON_WIDTH - CIRCLE_WIDTH) / 2;
        g2.fillOval(x, x, width, width);
        g2.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            if (label.getIcon() == whiteIcon) {
                System.out.println("error -- ignoring this press");
                return;
            }

            if (label1 == null) {
                // first press
                label1 = label;
            } else {
                JLabel label2 = label;
                int row1 = (int) label1.getClientProperty(ROW);
                int col1 = (int) label1.getClientProperty(COLUMN);
                int row2 = (int) label2.getClientProperty(ROW);
                int col2 = (int) label2.getClientProperty(COLUMN);

                Icon icon1 = label1.getIcon();
                Icon icon2 = label2.getIcon();

                // just to show that this works:
                System.out.printf("Locaions: [%d, %d] [%d, %d]%n",
                        row1, col1, row2, col2);

                if (checkLinearity(row1, col1, row2, col2)) {
                    // TODO: do something
                }

                label1 = null; // reset this
            }
        }

        private boolean checkLinearity(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
            // TODO finish this method
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DriverV2b mainPanel = new DriverV2b();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DriverV2b");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

added error testing for whiteIcon press